# Checking http response codes to display appropriate failure message

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I have a javascript function that takes form data and send it to a server via a http post request. I now need to check that the status code returned is 201 and display an error message otherwise:

```
function load(){

console.log(document);
var form = document.getElementById("myform");

form.onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();

  // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }

  // construct an HTTP request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

  // send the collected data as JSON
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

  xhr.onloadend = function () {
    // done
  };
};
}
```

Does the xhr have any specific method by which this can be done? I've been doing a lot of googling and came across this, but I don't think statusCheck is predefined?

```
if (statusCheck(server url)) != 201
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normally just `status`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 201) {
    //        ^^ request complete      ^^ and returned status was 201
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add in an else if statement after that to say if xhr.status != 201, how would I get the browser to show the code and error message?

Comment: Like you would show anything else really, in the condition do something like `element.innerHTML = 'Error - 201'`